# Kubernetes/Flannel doens't work in private network

Tags: kubernetes

I am able to run kubernetes (via kubeadm) on a private cluster/cloud without issue only when the nodes in the cluster have access to the internet (all node are connected to a dumb switch, which then has a network cable out to a gateway).

If I remove the network cable that gives nodes access to the internet and then try to setup my cluster and containers again. I get the following error on flannel:

```
I0720 21:55:48.351628       1 main.go:459] Using interface with name eth2 and address 192.168.10.1
I0720 21:55:48.351782       1 main.go:476] Defaulting external address to interface address (192.168.10.1)
E0720 21:55:48.358553       1 main.go:223] Failed to create SubnetManager: error retrieving pod spec for 'kube-system/kube-flannel-ds-zr17s': Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/kube-flannel-ds-zr17s: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: connect: network is unreachable
```

I'm having a hard time understand why would flannel need accesses to the internet? FYI, when connect via switch, I am able to communicate between nodes without issue using static IPs

Comment: Flannel does not need public internet access. The error indicates that flannel cannot reach the API server on 10.96.0.1 -- Can you provide the IP range associated with your public interface, as well as the API server address, and service details? kubectl describe svc

Comment: When you disconnected from your local network, did you also disconnect from IP management? I.e. Something local providing DHCP leases or something, which caused the IP address `10.96.0.1` to be invalid? Flannel will still need the underlying IP networks to be up and running, and the error message above indicates it can't get there.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I believe the issue is that when the Internet connection goes away, the default route disappears and flannel can no longer bootstrap itself on that node. Just make sure that your nodes have a default route configured.

You can check by running:

```
$ ip route
```

If no default route is listed you can add one from the command-line like this:

```
$ ip route add default via <gateway_ip> dev <net_device>
```

where `<gateway_ip>` is the IP address of your "gateway" and `<net_device>` is `eth0` (or whatever network device name is relevant in your case).

Comment: use the etcd flag --iface to specify the desired network interface